# How to set up the contour for $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{1+x^4}dx $?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{1+x^4}dx $$

From what I understand, since we have the complex exponential we consider the poles not only in the upper half plane but in the whole plane but then is the contour a circle englobing all poles or 2 semi-circles, one in the upper half plane, one in the lower half plane, each containing 2 poles? Or is it something else?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: if $a>0$ ($a<0$), you want just the upper (lower) half-plane, as$$|\exp(iaRe^{i\theta})|=\exp(-aR\sin\theta).$$So if $a>0$ the final result is$$2\pi i\sum_{n\in\{1,\,3\}}\operatorname{Res}_{z=e^{ni\pi/4}}\frac{e^{iaz}}{1+z^4},$$which I leave you to calculate.

Comment: @J.G. I saw something about the sign, I assumed a>0 but when calculating the residue I had some pretty wild results which made me doubt my contour. Cheers!

Comment: @J.G. if you could just help on the following, how can I simplify $e^{ia(e^{i\pi/4})}$?

Comment: It's$$e^{ae^{3i\pi/4}}=e^{-a/\sqrt{2}+ia/\sqrt{2}}=e^{-a/\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}+i\sin\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=e^{-a/\sqrt{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Comment: @J.G. ok thank you, did not thing of using that trig identity!

Comment: @J.G. are you sure about this identity, I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Sorry, the last $=$ is wrong. I was skipping ahead mentally to the final result, in which the two residues' results sum a sine and cosine, and the integral is proportional to $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.